Reactive variable changed based on values in props
The reactive variable state.deleteMessage is changed to '' every time props.cluster (passed from parent component) is updated. Since I display this deleteMessage on the page, I want to control its value from javascript instead of being updated based on props variable. At the same time, I need deleteMessage to be reactive so the HTML element will be updated promptly whenever deleteMessage is changed. Is there any way to stop deleteMessage being affected by elements in cluster?
const props = defineProps({
  cluster: Object,
  fetchData: Function
});

const state = reactive({
  loading: false,
  deleteMessage: '',
  showConfirmation: false,
})


props and state as they are defined here are two completely separate variables and would have no impact on each other when updating either.  You'll need to post enough code to reproduce the issue. Try reproducing the issue with the minimum code necessary in a sandbox like Vue Playground then add it to your question.

Thank you, your comment makes me realize what the issue was, deleteMessage was not affected by props.cluster. The corresponding html element(holding deleteMessage) disappears because the whole child component doesn't exist any more after the corresponding cluster was deleted.
